Extend styles into child component via styled component
I have a child component called Label. I want the parent component to add more styles in it by extending the styles, I have followed a few documentation to do this but it's not working.
It's a react-native CLI app.
Label.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Colors from '../ui/colors';

type Props = {
  color?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};

export const Label: React.FC<Props> = ({ color, children, className }) => {
  return (
    <StyledText color={color} className={className}>
      {children}
    </StyledText>
  );
};

const StyledText = styled(Text)<Props>`
  color: ${(props) => (props?.color ? props.color : Colors.textColor)};
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Poppins-SemiBold;
`;

Parent.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../../ui/layouts/Layout';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Label, Line } from '../../design-system';


const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <StyledLabel>Some random text</StyledLabel>
      <Line />
    </Layout>
  );
};

const StyledLabel = styled(Label)`
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: red;
`;

export default Parent;


I asked chatGPT about the problem by sharing the same codes. So I need to use style prop instead of className as it is a react-native app, not React.js. Here is the updated Label component.
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native'; // Use styled-components/native for React Native
import Colors from '../ui/colors';

type Props = {
  color?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  style?: TextStyle;
};

export const Label: React.FC<Props> = ({ color, children, style }) => {
  return (
    <StyledText color={color} style={style}>
      {children}
    </StyledText>
  );
};

const StyledText = styled(Text)<Props>`
  color: ${(props) => (props?.color ? props.color : Colors.textColor)};
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Poppins-SemiBold;
`;

